# Does $O(n\cdot n!) = O(n!)$?

Tags: computational-complexity

Does $O(n\cdot n!) = O(n!)$?

I know that $n*n! < (n+1)!$, and in Big Oh we usually throw out constants, so it seems like we could make this conclusion. However I am not sure how to show this mathematically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the ratio:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\cdot n!}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty\;,$$

so $n\cdot n!$ cannot be $O(n!)$.

Answer (score 2):

We don't throw out constants. See, suppose we have $O(n^2)$; now what is that little figure **2**? A variable? Definitely not. A constant? Surely! Can't we just throw it away?

We may throw out additive constants, but that's another story.

Comment: Right, I was referring to additive constants. However I was unsure whether you could still do this if a function was operating on the sum of a variable and a constant. The above answers have cleared this up, though.